# How to use getViewLifecycleOwner() in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-livedata

My custom fragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment. I have ViewModel and I observe some LiveData objects. I want to use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` in my observers. But it crashes with this log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()
```

BottomSheetDialog uses `onCreateDialog()` and hence `onViewCreated()` is not called. Putting my observers in `onActivityCreated()` also not solving this crash.

Answer (score -1):

If putting the code inside `onActivityCreated()` doesn't work, try using         `getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData()` and observe on it for the `LifecycleOwner`.

---

Not exactly what you asked for, but if you just want the fragment's `LifeCycle`, I believe you can get it with something like this:

```
 @NonNull
 @Override
 public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
     return super.getLifecycle();
 }
```